# How to make rows become columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, rows

I want the first dataset to change into the second. I tried attempting dcast() from reshape2 library but I'm not successful with it. How I may achieve such a dataframe transformation in R?

**Given dataframe**

| date | employee | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jan1 | Alex | 200 |
| jan2 | Alex | 210 |
| jan3 | Alex | 167 |
| jan1 | Tom | 212 |
| jan2 | Tom | 222 |
| jan3 | Tom | 189 |
| jan1 | Kim | 210 |
| jan2 | Kim | 210 |
| jan3 | Kim | 208 |

**Desired dataframe**

| employee | jan1 | jan2 | jan3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 200 | 210 | 167 |
| Tom | 212 | 222 | 189 |
| Kim | 210 | 210 | 208 |

Comment: Use pivot_wider from tidyverse

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = date,
                      values_from = outcome)
```